# Binding textbox values to a model in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf app.

I have successfully bounded listviews to ObservableCollections.

I now want to do the same thing with a textbox and I have just a standard class model (no collection).

So, i have a static class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public Static Class MyClass
    {
        public string MyField {get; set;}
    }
}
```

and in my markup:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyField}/>
```

But I get a run-time error to this declaration in my markup?

ADDITIONAL:
In response to the answer this is the code used (but it does not work)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:Model></vms:Model>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path='MyField'}"/>
          <Button Content="Click Me!" Click="Button_Click" />  
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>



using System.ComponentModel;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string myField;
        public string MyField
        {
            get { return myField; }
            set
            {
                myField = value;
                Raise("MyField ");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void Raise(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}

using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Model myModel = new Model();


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myModel.MyField = "has worked";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *i have a static class* seems you don't, your code has no static keyword anywhere - apart from that the question is if it really should be static? Why not just make an instance of MyClass and set the ui's DataContext to it, then use normal `{Binding MyField}`?

Comment: You should initialize the DataContext of view.

Comment: @stijn Hi thanks for your comment. I forgot the Static prefix when copying over. i will add now. However, static or instance makes no difference but I prefer static for my needs. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @user1672994 Googling that now. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @stijn Read the last part of what you said. is there anyway to bind it in way I want to?

Comment: Your textbox and MyField will not stay in sync, because you need to implement INotifyPropertyChange.

Comment: @adminSoftDK thanks (this is my 1st wpf app). Would it be acceptable to create an observablecolelction with just 1 entry in it and use that as a binder rather than the event you suggested or should i use what you suggested?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - what is your requirement? Do you have to show only as a readonly text and any changes in control should not update the target property?

Comment: @user1672994 Hi, thanks for your interest. This properties are all editable. i wish to update the model when the User changes values and then when the User presses the Save button I upload as a JSON object to my server. This bit I have done already.  I got fed up with WinForm and just started using WPF

Comment: ObservableCollection notifies the UI, only when you add or remove an item, in your case MyClass. It will not notify is something inside that item changes in your case MyField. If you google INotifyPropertyChange you'll find lots of forums and posts about it.

Comment: @adminSoftDK sorry for the delay. was called away - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include namespace `xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"`

and use `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:MyClass.MyField}}" />` for binding for binding static class.

Whole test code as below:
**XML file as:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:MyClass.MyField}}" Margin="10"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**CODE BEHIND FILE AS**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Test.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Test : Window
    {
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        static MyClass()
        {
            MyField = "Testing";
        }
        public static string MyField {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, got multiple errors doing that...would you like to post a full answer based on my example?

Comment: hi, thanks for that.There are no errors but if I now add a button to the UI like so:

Comment: private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass.MyField = "Andy";
        }

Comment: the text does not change on the UI?

Comment: If you are using WPF 4.5 then check it: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your class is not static then you can bind the TextBox to your control with following steps :

1. Define the namespace:

   ```
   xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:Your namespace"
   ```
2. Define the DataContext:

   ```
   <Window.DataContext><vms:MyClass></vms:MyClass></Window.DataContext>
   ```
3. Binding would be as:

   ```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path="MyField"}/>
   ```
4. If you have to update the text from control to source then your VM should implement INotifyPropetyChanged.

   ```
   public class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {   
   private string myField ;
   public string MyField 
   {
       get { return MyField ; }
       set 
       { 
           MyField = value;
           Raise("MyField ");
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void Raise(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Just a small addition in your Rise method, you can use [CallerMemberName] stringPropertyName="", then you don't have to pass that magic string, you would just call Raise();

Comment: @adminSoftDK only works in .net 4.5 onwards though. Btw. you can encapsulate the setter in an if-clause to check if the value actually changed. UI updates are costly and you wouldn't want to fire the whole event chain uncessarily.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked this and it did not work for me,  i will edit my question to include the example I used