# Binding textbox without static class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem to bind a subclass to my XML textbox, I followed this post to do it, but it does not work without using a static class.  Is there a way to do without using a static class?

I followed this post as reference.

[Binding textbox values to a model in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220594/binding-textbox-values-to-a-model-in-wpf)

My code is:

```
public class Model:INotifyPropertyChanged{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private string title;
    public string Title{
            get {
                return title;
            }
            set {
                if (tilte!= value) {
                    tilte= value;

                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}


public class ViewModel{

        public Model modelObj;

        public ViewModel(){
             modelObj= new Model();
             this.DataContext = modelObj;    

             modelObj.Title = "New title"; // <--- this don't update xml
        }
}

<Page
    x:Class="AppTest.Demo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:m ="using:Models"
    xmlns:vm ="using:ViewModels"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <m:Model></m:Model>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your view model as the data context and bind to Model.Title.

**Update**

This works:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication8.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:m ="using:Models"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8.ViewModels">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModelObj.Title, TargetNullValue='null', FallbackValue='fallback'}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Model : BindableBase
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private Model modelObj;

    public Model ModelObj
    {
        get
        {
            return modelObj;
        }

        set
        {
            modelObj = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ModelObj = new Model();

        ModelObj.Title = "New title"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean .  <TextBlock DataContext="ViewModel"  Text="{Binding Path=Model.Title}"/> I already try and does not work.

Comment: Work as charm! I also thinked in put INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the view model. Thank you, good work.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `Title` property of the instance of the `Model` class that you set as the `DataContext` of the Page:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <m:Model Title="New title"></m:Model>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Or:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <m:ViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=modelObj.Title}"/>
</Grid>
```

Also, you don't set the `DataContext` property of a view model. You set the `DataContext` property of a view to an instance of a view model.

**Edit:**

`modelObj` must be a public *property* (and not a field) in order for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public Model modelObj { get; set; }
```

Comment: Weird... Of the two way I get an empty texblock.

Comment: Do you set the DataContext of the Page somewhere else, for example in Demo.xaml.cs?

Comment: Oh yes work! I forgot set DataContext in MainPage.xaml.cs 

`ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
DataContext = vm.modelObj;`

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>`

But if I put `DataContext = vm`in MainPage, and `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Model.Title}"/>` in Xaml as your example it does not work.

Comment: If you set the DataContext to vm.modelObj you should bind to the Title property directly: {Binding Title}. The binding path refers to a property of the DataContext.

Comment: Yes, it work.. but I don't understand why doesn't work when I directly use DataContext = vm and Binding Path=Model.Title

Comment: modelObj must be a public property (and not a field) in order for you to be able to bind to it: {Binding modelObj.Title}. Also note that the property names are case-sensitive. I edited my answer to clarify this.